# Poylgon не всегда закрашивает внутреню часть

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps, google-play-services

Есть коодинаты и при добавлении их в полигон границы рисуются но внутрь не закрашиваеться.Как правильно их отсортировать чтоб внутрь всегда закрашиваля.Вот мои координаты .Но они будут изменятся поэтому нужен метод.искал в гугле ничего рабочаего не нашел .Благодарю!

```
   PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions()
                .add(new LatLng(40.494220, 49.839761),
                        new LatLng(40.481445, 49.805932),
                        new LatLng(40.465294, 49.819697),
                        new LatLng(40.486058, 49.878257),
                        new LatLng(40.464762, 49.845827),
                        new LatLng(40.440617, 49.849327));
        rectOptions.geodesic(true);


// Get back the mutable Polygon
        Polygon polygon = mMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);
        polygon.setGeodesic(true);
        polygon.setFillColor(getColor(R.color.be1));
        polygon.setStrokeColor(getColor(R.color.be1));
        polygon.setStrokeWidth(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте применить следующий код javascript Google Maps API:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Polygon Arrays</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      // This example creates a simple polygon representing the Bermuda Triangle.
      // When the user clicks on the polygon an info window opens, showing
      // information about the polygon's coordinates.

      var map;
      var infoWindow;

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 5,
          center: {lat: 24.886, lng: -70.268},
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.
        var triangleCoords = [
            {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
            {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
            {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757}
        ];

        // Construct the polygon.
        var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: triangleCoords,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 3,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
        bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);

        // Add a listener for the click event.
        bermudaTriangle.addListener('click', showArrays);

        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      }

      /** @this {google.maps.Polygon} */
      function showArrays(event) {
        // Since this polygon has only one path, we can call getPath() to return the
        // MVCArray of LatLngs.
        var vertices = this.getPath();

        var contentString = '<b>Bermuda Triangle polygon</b><br>' +
            'Clicked location: <br>' + event.latLng.lat() + ',' + event.latLng.lng() +
            '<br>';

        // Iterate over the vertices.
        for (var i =0; i < vertices.getLength(); i++) {
          var xy = vertices.getAt(i);
          contentString += '<br>' + 'Coordinate ' + i + ':<br>' + xy.lat() + ',' +
              xy.lng();
        }

        // Replace the info window's content and position.
        infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
        infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

        infoWindow.open(map);
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Источник: **[документация Google Maps API "Polygon Arrays"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays)**.

Comment: СПасибо.Да заработало\!